# How to make an object of association comparable by only one generic parameter type

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I'm trying to understand what `<K, V extends Comparable<? super V>>` actually means.

If `compareTo()` is called to compare two `Association<K,V>` objects; which of the two generic types `K` or `V` will be used to make the comparison?

What will happen when `<K, V extends Comparable<? super K>>` is used instead?

```html
public class Association<K, V extends Comparable<? super V>>
{
 K key;
 V value;
 //---------------------------------------
  
        public int compareTo(Association<K, V> object) 
 {
  return this.key.compareTo(object.key);
 }
}
```

edited the `compareTo()` method.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong with your `compareTo()` method. You will get stack overflow with this.

Comment: As you have it now, `Association` is not `Comparable`, only `V` is.

Comment: @TiiJ7 I only want to compare `Association` by using `K`, your comment is very helpful.
@Jai I have edited the `compareTo()` method to reflect the objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to explain your current definition:

```
public class Association<K, V extends Comparable<? super V>>
```

This means you are defining a public class called `Association` This class has 2 type parameters: `K` and `V`. Of these, `V` has the additional restraint that it must be comparable to `? super V` (= `V` or a super type of `V`).

Since you want ot compare by the key, it should be `K` that is `Comparable`. Additionally, you want to compare the `Association`s themselves, so it too must be `Comparable`.

So change your class definition to the following:

```
public class Association<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Comparable<Association<K, V>>
```

Your compareTo would then be:

```
public int compareTo(Association<K, V> other) {
    return key.compareTo(other.key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If compareTo() is called to compare two Association objects; which of the two generic types K or V will be used to make the comparison?

As `Association` is implemented right now, neither will be used.  Instead, your `compareTo` method will always throw a `StackOverflowError`, because it's incorrectly defined.

(The implication is that it's the responsibility of the `Association` class and its definition of `compareTo` to decide what the answer to your question is.  For example, you might write `public int compareTo(Association<K, V> other) { return value.compareTo(other.value); }`. )

Comment: How would I change my `<K, V extends Comparable<? super V>>` statement such that I am able to write `public int compareTo(Association<K, V> other) { return key.compareTo(other.key); }` such that I may compare by `K` and not by `V`.